# How to plot monthly and daily data in same canvas

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with over 5,000 records here https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6b678858616ea970a0

My last column (sal) is monthly data and my other columns are daily data. I have tried many ways to plot it together in the same r device but my 'sal' column prints some weird lines. My other graphics are plotted correctly. Could some one give me a hint on how I can summarize 'sal' to be only one value per month to plot it on my bottom graphic using facet_wrap? Here is some code that I have tried:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(readxl)
 library(lubridate)
tab <- read_excel("myjoinedfile.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1")
test <- tab %>% pivot_longer(-c("year","day","date","month")) %>% data.frame()
ggplot(test, aes(x = date, y = value,colour=year)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.75) +  t
  facet_wrap(name~.,switch = "y",ncol=1) +  
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("1991-10-01"),as.Date("1992-09-30"),
    by = "1 month"),date_labels = "%b")
```

All my graphics print correctly but the bottom one is not displaying correctly because is so many repeated values on column 'sal'. I unsuccessfully tried to get the mean with pivot_longer() Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. Aggregate you column `sal` by `month` and `year`, add the `name` and the `date`. Here I set the date to the first of the month. But you could change that.
2. Convert your data to long except column `sal`
3. Bind the two df together.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
tab <- read_excel("myjoinedfile.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1")

test1 <- select(tab, year, month, sal) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(sal), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(name = "sal", 
         date = ifelse(month < 10, 1992, 1991),
         date = paste(date, month, "01", sep = "-"),
         date = as.Date(date))
  
test2 <- tab %>% 
  select(-sal) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c("year","day","date","month")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))

test <- bind_rows(test1, test2)

ggplot(test, aes(x = date, y = value,colour=year)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.75) +
facet_wrap(name~.,switch = "y",ncol=1) +  
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("1991-10-01"),as.Date("1992-09-30"),
                            by = "1 month"),date_labels = "%b")
```

[image]

Comment: --@stefan-- Thanks, it works as expected. One thing that I noticed though, is the date for 'sal'. It starts in Oct 1 but end in Sept 1. How can I make it end in Sept 30? Notice how the bottom graphic end sooner than the others.

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately I'm afraid there is no perfect solution to this. The issue is that in case of the monthly data we have to decide on which day we want to show the data. I decided for the first of month which leaves a gap at the end. Another option would be to chose the middle, e..g. `date = paste(date, month, "15", sep = "-")`. Of course could you choose different days for each month, e.g. you could do `ifelse(month == 9, paste(date, month, "30", sep = "-"), paste(date, month, "01", sep = "-"))`. However, in that case you end up with a line starting on Aug 1 and ending on Sept 30.

Comment: I am trying  `date=seq.Date (from = as.Date('1991-10-01'), to = as.Date('1992-09-30'), by = 'month')` but also gives me the first day of every month. I wonder if there is a workaround on this.